# How to write soql query with open, close braces

Tags: apex, soql

I need the dynamic SOQL query with open braces and closed. But I am not getting that... need query like

```
select field1__c, field2__c from Object__c where field1__c = id AND (field2__c == 'abc' OR field2__c == 'jkl').
```

I tried like this my exact query below

```
string teamquery = 'select '+packageNamespace+'Response_Date__c,'+packageNamespace+'RBM_Template_Team__r.name,'+packageNamespace+'Participant_Name__c,'+packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name from '+packageNamespace+'RBM_Template_Team__c where '+packageNamespace+'RBM_Template__c = \'' + recid +'\'';
    string temp = packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name = \''+'Project Manager'+'\'';
    temp += ' OR '+ packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name = \''+'Statistician'+'\'';
    temp += ' OR '+ packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name = \''+'Medical Monitor'+'\'';

    teamquery += ' AND (\''+temp+'\')'; 
    MyQuery = DataBase.query(teamquery);
```

but I am getting error
unexpected token: 'CTMax__Role__r.Name = ' 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

I got the solution, updated below line..
teamquery += ' AND ('+temp+')';

Comment: The error should be pretty prescriptive. What was it

Comment: @Eric, error showing like this unexpected token: 'field2__c = '

Comment: Post the exact error message. And you need to put you criteria in quotes. abc should be \'abc\' etc

Comment: Missing a space here: `OR'+ packageNamespace+'field2__c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
string teamquery = 'SELECT field1__c, field2__c '+
                   'FROM ' +packageNamespace+'Object__c '+
                   'WHERE '+ packageNamespace+'field1__c = ' + recid + 
                   ' AND (' +packageNamespace+'field2__c = \'abc\' OR '+ packageNamespace+'field2__c  = \'jkl\')'; 
system.debug(teamquery);

MyQuery = DataBase.query(teamquery);
```

As you updated your actual query, need to modify like this.

```
string teamquery = 'select '+packageNamespace+'Response_Date__c,'+packageNamespace+'RBM_Template_Team__r.name,'+packageNamespace+'Participant_Name__c,'+packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name '+
                    'from '+packageNamespace+'RBM_Template_Team__c '+
                    'where '+packageNamespace+'RBM_Template__c = ' + recid;

string temp = packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name = \'Project Manager\'';
temp += ' OR '+ packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name = \'Statistician\'';
temp += ' OR '+ packageNamespace+'Role__r.Name = \'Medical Monitor\'';

teamquery += ' AND ('+temp+')';
MyQuery = DataBase.query(teamquery);
```

Comment: @VijayKumar Did this work for you?

Comment: @VijayKumar so you'll come back to respond to an answer that gave you another  error but won't help us help you by posting the info requested?